# Reselect saved ISelectionSet

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.4

I currently have an ISelectionSet that has various features from different layers.

When I submit my edits to the Geodatabase, I lose my selection in ArcMap.

Is there a fast way to take the ISelectionSet that I saved and reselect that ISelectionSet?

Here is a brief overview of what my code looks like:

```
ISelectionSet savedSet = GetSelectionSet();

m_editor.StartEditing(GetWorkspaceBasedOnLayer(ManholeLayer));
//Make Edits To Rows Here
tempFeature.Store();
m_editor.StopEditing(true);
//Here is where the selection set is being cleared.
```